# Switch tab in android but content not change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have class CustomTab extends TabActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.custom_tab);

tabHost = getTabHost();

Intent intentA = new Intent(getBaseContext(), A.class);
Intent intentB = new Intent(getBaseContext(), B.class);
Intent intentC = new Intent(getBaseContext(), C.class);

TabSpec tabA = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("a")
        .setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_a))
        .setContent(intentA);
TabSpec tabB = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("b")
        .setIndicator(
                "",
                getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_b))
        .setContent(intentB);
TabSpec tabC = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("c")
        .setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_c))
        .setContent(intentC);


tabHost.addTab(tabA);
tabHost.addTab(tabB);
tabHost.addTab(tabC);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

and activity B:

```
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.b);

((CustomTab) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(3);
```

I want switch to tab 3(activity C) when run activity B so I tried with "((CustomTab) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(3);" it only change tab, but content not change, I created a topic similar but not receive correct answer.

Comment: "it only change tab, but content not change" As you have written the code for changing the Tab only so it will only change the Tab. You have also code for loading the activity in your Tab 3 in your activity B.

Comment: Try this.........                                              ((CustomTab) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);

Comment: I think just setCurrentTab because its content has written in CustomTab class: TabSpec....setContent(...). I will try

Comment: getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);  you can try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed this things calling TabActivity again.

In `TabActivity`

```
int tabNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tabNumber");
tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabNumber);
```

And calling TabActivity in child Activity like your Activity B like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BActivity.this,
                            CustomTab.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("tabNumber",3);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Dont no its correct solution for this or not. but I havn't got any other solution. 
So, i used this.

Comment: thank for your help, it has worked, but sometime it automated change tab